# GNU as equivalent to times X db 0

Tags: nasm, gnu, gnu-assembler

I'm writing a small bootloader in GNU `as` and I need to make the binary output "BIOS-compatible". Here is how I do it in `nasm`:

```
...
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

But how can I do it in GNU `as`?

Comment: If you put a label at the start of your bootloader code called `start` then you could do something like `.space 510-(.-start)` and then `.word 0xaa55`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some Google-searching, I figured out how to do it:

```
_start:
...
.fill 510 - (. - _start), 0
.word 0xAA55
```